# Android: How can I change the typeface of the message of a indeterminate ProgressDialog

Tags: android, android-dialog

I need to change the typefaces of the `ProgressDialog`'s.

I can change the typeface of a horizontal style `progressDialog` this way:

```
                progressProzent = new ProgressDialog(mActivity);
            if (passUrlVector.size() > 1) {
                progressProzent.setTitle(mActivity.getString(R.string.Lade_Tickets));
                String message = String.format(mActivity.getString(R.string.Tickets_Werden_heruntergeladen), passUrlVector.size());
                progressProzent.setMessage(message);
            } else {
                progressProzent.setTitle(mActivity.getString(R.string.Lade_Ticket));
                progressProzent.setMessage(mActivity.getString(R.string.Ticket_Wird_heruntergeladen));
            }
            progressProzent.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressProzent.setProgressNumberFormat(null);
            progressProzent.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressProzent.setCancelable(false);
            progressProzent.show();
            try {
                TextView textView = (TextView) progressProzent.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                textView.setTypeface(TypefaceUtil.georgia);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("PROGRESS", "Exception = ", e);
            }
```

I can change the typeface of the title of a indeterminate `ProgressDialog` this way:

```
            progress = new ProgressDialog(this);

        progressShowListener = new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                Log.i("entered", "show listner");
                try {
                    final int idAlertTitle=getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier( "alertTitle", "id", "android" );
                    TextView dialogTitle=(TextView)((AlertDialog)dialog).findViewById(idAlertTitle);

                    dialogTitle.setTypeface(TypefaceUtil.neutraBurgDemi);

                    TextView textView = (TextView) progress.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                                        textView.setTypeface(TypefaceUtil.georgia);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("PROGRESS", "Exception = ", e);
                }
            }
        };
        progress.setOnShowListener(progressShowListener);
```

But the message typeface does not change to Georgia font. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context):    
    progressDialog.show();  
    TextView tv1 = (TextView) progressDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);   
    tv1.setTypeface(yourCustomTF);
```

Remember, you can get the view Id by using findViewById() after progressDialog.show() because the view is generated after show().

Comment: Your solution works only for a horizontal style ProgressDialog, but not for a spinner style indeterminate ProgressDialog.